# PHP MYSQL runs the query twice

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

When i run the following script. The row is inserted **twice** ( the query runs twice ) .

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/sanitize.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/config.php';

$response    =   textsanitize($_POST['r']);
$ticket      =   idssanitize($_POST['t']);

$stmt = $condb->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket_reponses (ticket_id,user_id,time,response) VALUES (:ticket_id,:user_id,:time,:response)");
$stmt->execute(
array(
"ticket_id" => $ticket,
"user_id" => $_SESSION['user_id'],
"time" => time(),
"response" => $response
)
);
if($stmt->execute()){
   echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

When i remove `if($stmt->execute()){echo "SUCCESSS";}`. It runs in the right way. The row inserted once.

Why does `if($stmt->execute())` execute the query again ? I thought that `if($stmt->execute())` only returns `TRUE || FALSE`. I want to ensure that the query was executed successfully.

Comment: _“Why does if($stmt->execute()) execute the query again ?”_ - because that’s plain and simple what this method _does_, it _executes_ the statement. You called this method twice, so it performs its job twice. Surprise. Catch the result of the first call in a variable, and then use that variable in your if condition.

Comment: You need to put your `if()` around the first (and only) `$stmt->execute()` with all of the parameters you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the good uses of prepared statements in any language is that you can prepare it once and then execute it as many times as needed.

So in your case you `execute()` the statement twice, but it's possible that you could insert a whole bunch of data with the same prepared statement in a loop.  Each time you call `execute()` you can just pass a new set of values to run the prepared statement.  In your case it is an INSERT, so this is run twice.

In your case you probably just need...

```
$stmt = $condb->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket_reponses (ticket_id,user_id,time,response) VALUES (:ticket_id,:user_id,:time,:response)");

if($stmt->execute(array(
                  "ticket_id" => $ticket,
                  "user_id" => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                  "time" => time(),
                  "response" => $response)))    {
   echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is calling the `$stmt->execute()` function twice. Once before the if statement and once as the condition in the if statement.
So, you need to remove one instance of it.

I believe that you need to check if the statement has executed correctly (hence the if). So, the code can be like...

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/sanitize.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/config.php';

$response    =   textsanitize($_POST['r']);
$ticket      =   idssanitize($_POST['t']);

$stmt = $condb->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket_reponses  (ticket_id,user_id,time,response) VALUES (:ticket_id,:user_id,:time,:response)");
$values = array(
    "ticket_id" => $ticket,
    "user_id" => $_SESSION['user_id'],
    "time" => time(),
    "response" => $response
);
if($stmt->execute($values)){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are executing `$stmt->execute()` twice, so it's simply inserting two rows. no rocket science here.

if you want to check if the query ran successfully or not do it in the first statement itself.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/sanitize.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/config.php';

$response    =   textsanitize($_POST['r']);
$ticket      =   idssanitize($_POST['t']);

$stmt = $condb->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket_reponses (ticket_id,user_id,time,response) VALUES (:ticket_id,:user_id,:time,:response)");
$isSuccessful = $stmt->execute(
array(
"ticket_id" => $ticket,
"user_id" => $_SESSION['user_id'],
"time" => time(),
"response" => $response
)
);
if($isSuccessful){
   echo "SUCCESS";
}
```